# Annihilator of a quotient module over a local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

> Assume $R$ is a commutative local ring, $I$ is a proper ideal in $R$ and $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. Is it true that $\operatorname{Ann}(M/IM)=I+\operatorname{Ann}(M)$?

(Note that $\supseteq$ is clear.)

If it's true I would like (a hint for) an elementary proof (preferably avoiding any homological algebra).

Comment: Some related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79538/annihilator-of-quotient-module-m-im and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811875/annihilator-of-a-quotient-module. However I did not find the answer there.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/79548/121097) contains a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically only a power of $Ann(M/IM)$ will be contained in $I+Ann (M)$. For a simple example, take the `universal' example. Let $R$ be the power series over a field in three variables $x,y,z$. Consider the module $M$ given as the quotient of the free module $Re_1\oplus Re_2$ by $xe_1+ye_2, ze_1+xe_2$. You can easily check that $Ann(M)$ is the ideal generated by $x^2-yz$, and if $I=(y,z)$, then $Ann(M/IM)=(x,y,z)$.